# List of all upcoming reservations within the next 30 days for a selected park - PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need a PostgresSQL query that will list all upcoming reservations within the next 30 days for a selected park

```
Table: reservation
Columns: reservation_id, site_id, name, from_date, to_date, create_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `from_date` in the `WHERE` between `CURRENT_DATE` and `CURRENT_DATE + 30`:

```
SELECT * FROM reservations
WHERE 
  from_date >= CURRENT_DATE AND from_date <= CURRENT_DATE + 30 AND
  site_id = 42;
```

.. or use `interval '30 days'`:

```
SELECT * FROM reservations
WHERE 
  from_date >= CURRENT_DATE AND from_date <= CURRENT_DATE + interval '30 days' 
  AND site_id = 42;
```

Comment: Thank you, I re-checked and it works fine

Comment: @TsiT nice. Consider accepting and upvoting the answer, so that other users may also profit from it. cheers and happy coding.